# Text reappearing in TextField after creating a new user

Tags: swift

// Alright I need to clear the text field as soon as the logout button is pressed. "inputToolbar" is the variable I am using in the MessagesViewController, but the logout button is on another screen.

```
@IBAction func logoutUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setObject("", forKey: "user")
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFUser.logOut()

    MessagesViewController.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.resignFirstResponder()

    //Segue to Splash Screen
    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
MessagesViewController.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.resignFirstResponder()
```

You're dismissing the keyboard, which would not be in view at this point.

To clear the text view, you will need reset its text property with:

```
MessagesViewController.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.text = ""
```